# Segmentation error when trying to print out a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Working on a pokedex project using linked lists, after creating a node and attempting to print I am getting this error I am pretty new to C so would not be surprised if this is a stupid mistake.

```c
signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Pokemon {
  char pokemonName[50];
  char pokemonType[20];
  char pokemonAbility[50];

  struct Pokemon *next;
} Pokemon;

Pokemon* NewPokemonNode(char pokemonName[50],char pokemonType[20], char pokemonAbility[50]) {

  Pokemon *new_node = NULL;
  new_node = malloc(sizeof(Pokemon));

  if (new_node != NULL){

    strcpy(new_node -> pokemonName, pokemonName);
    strcpy(new_node -> pokemonType, pokemonType);
    strcpy(new_node -> pokemonAbility, pokemonAbility);

    new_node->next = NULL;   
  }
  return new_node;
}

int main(void){
  Pokemon *head = NULL;

  NewPokemonNode("Bulbasaur", "Grass", "Overgrow");
  
  Pokemon *tempPointer = head;
  while (tempPointer->next != NULL)
  {

    printf("Working");

    tempPointer = tempPointer->next;

  }

}
```

Comment: Please post all code directly in the question as text, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: I'm not getting a segfault when I run your code.  Are you sure this is what's giving you the error?

Comment: Just pasted it in again must have put the wrong version in the question - error should appear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting segmentation fault because your code is dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.
Here, pointer `head` assigned `NULL`:

```
  Pokemon *head = NULL;
```

and then `tempPointer` is assigned `head`:

```
  Pokemon *tempPointer = head;
```

and then dereferencing `tempPointer` here:

```
  while (tempPointer->next != NULL)
```

May you want to assign the return value of `NewPokemonNode()` function to `head` pointer. But note that, `NewPokemonNode()` function may also return `NULL`, in case, when `malloc()` fails. So you should take care of that as well. Change the `while` loop condition to `tempPointer != NULL`.

```
    Pokemon *head = NULL;

    head = NewPokemonNode("Bulbasaur", "Grass", "Overgrow");

    Pokemon *tempPointer = head;
    while (tempPointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("Working");
        tempPointer = tempPointer->next;
    }
```